# Fancybox 2 multiple titles

Tags: fancybox-2

I am aware already of how to use data-caption as caption for my fancybox, and it's working fine.

My question is, is it possible to use both "over" and "float" with two separate content in them? Currently i data-tag the float type but I'd like to have an "over" version as well with added data.

I guess since fancybox defaults to one titletype, it might not be possible easily?

Here is a pic of what i try to achieve: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mafoo1chfy9s54f/sample.jpg?dl=0

Thanks, appreciated!

Comment: Is this a no go ? :) Please check the pic for an immediate thought on whether possible, or not. Calling an aftershow event, with a 'this' and reading additional data fields and overlaying that in proportion to the opened picture might work but I am not that pro unfortunately :D

Comment: I don't think it's possible using the normal `title`, you could try adding a `<div>` element on top of the image (using the `beforeShow` callback) though and style it so its absolutely position on the bottom of the `.fancybox-inner` (v2.x) container

Answer (score 0):

Yep, the beforeload callback was doable.